# error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so

Tags: java, ubuntu, plugins, processing

Ok, so I'm on Ubuntu(ZorinOS 12.1) and after I installed Java with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre
```

and I typed`java -version` I got this:
`Java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+171)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+171, mixed mode)`
 which is fine and all, but the problem began when I tried to start up the Processing from `processing.org`. I cd'd in its directory and ran `./processing`, but all I got was `user:~/processing-3.3.4$ ./processing
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and it ended the output, so nothing happened. Tried reinstalling Java and installing an older version, but no luck.

Please help, because I need Processing for school and school is nearing an end. If you need anything like an output, just comment.

Thanks to everyone!

EDIT:
ran `sudo find / -name "libjli.so"` and this is the output, so the `libjli.so` does exist.

```
notyours@notyours-K53SD:~$ sudo find / -name "libjli.so"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/lib/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
```

And about processing supporting my OS:
 Windows, Linux and MacOSX: https://processing.org/download/

Comment: Are you sure Processing supports your OS? Can you find the `libjli.so` file?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I updated my OP post.

Comment: What happens if you try using Java 8? I don't think Java 9 is standard yet. Also, what happens if you download the version of Processing that comes with its own Java?

Comment: this version of processing does include java...`notyours@notyours-K53SD:~/processing-3.3.4$ ls
core        java  modes       processing-java  tools
install.sh  lib   processing  revisions.txt    uninstall.sh`

Comment: I don't think any of those are Java. Those are directories. Anyway, what happens if you try Java 8?

Comment: Currently downloading it. And yes, there is a directory called "java" and it has java installation in it.

Comment: Purged openjdk-9-jre and installed openjdk-8-jre, but there is still the same problem. Could it be a problem with some kind of $PATH or directory linking?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Weird setup issues are the downside of working with Linux. Maybe try a Linux forum?

Comment: @MGlolenstine Might be a Linux - JVM issue, not necessarily Processing alone related as far as I can see from doing a [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22libjli.so%22&oq=%22libjli.so%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.799j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest version of Processing: https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/tag/processing-0262-3.3.5